# question about permutations with a combinatorial approach to solving

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

Question:
Let $\sigma \in S_9$ satisfy  $o(\sigma)=5$. How many $k \in [9]$ are there such that $\sigma(k)=k$?

I struggle with the combinatorics in this question.

I can see the permutation requires a 5-cycle which makes the cycle structure $[5,1,1,1,1]$ so the answer is ${9\choose5}\cdot4! $ ?

${9\choose5}$ represents the number of ways to choose the elements in the 5-cycle and $4!$ is the number of ways to choose the 4 elements s.t. $\sigma(k)=k$

Is this the correct way to think about the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: $\sigma$ is already fixed.  We aren't asking how many choices of $\sigma$ there are, we were just asking how many fixed points $\sigma$ has, which you correctly found that $\sigma$ has cycle structure $[5,1,1,1,1]$ so the answer is just $4$.

Comment: As an aside, while $\binom{9}{5}\cdot 4!$ is the correct answer for the number of $\sigma\in S_9$ satisfying $o(\sigma)=5$, you got the answer for the wrong reasons.  After having selected the five elements appearing in the five-cycle we then multiply by $4!$ here to decide *how the selected elements within the five-cycle are arranged*.  There is no further calculation to perform for the four fixed point elements.  We had picked them as a consequence of having picked which five appear in the cycle.